# how modify the legend on a Bar chart of Chartjs in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, chart.js

I have the next chart on `React`.

```
<Bar options={{
              responsive: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              plugins: {
                legend: {
                  position: 'top',
                },
                title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: `TRA ${selectedNivel === 'Division'?selectedDivision.toLocaleUpperCase():selectedNivel === 'Compañia' ?selectedAsegurado.toLocaleUpperCase():selectedComprador}`,
                  font: {
                    size: 18, // Tamaño de la fuente del título
                  },
                },
              },
              scales: {
                x: {
                  ticks: {
                    font: {
                      size: 14, // Tamaño de la fuente de las etiquetas del eje X
                    },
                  },
                },
                y: {
                  ticks: {
                    font: {
                      size: 14, // Tamaño de la fuente de las etiquetas del eje Y
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            }} data={{
              labels,
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: `Declarado por ${selectedNivel === 'Division'?selectedDivision:selectedAsegurado}`,
                  data: dataGrafVentas.map(obj =>  Number((parseFloat(obj.Suma_Ventas_del_mes_USD) / selectedFactorNumeros * selectedCambio).toFixed(0))),
                  backgroundColor: '#007bb2',
                },
                {
                  label: 'TRA',
                  data: dataGrafVentas.map(obj =>  Number((parseFloat(obj.Suma_Ventas_del_mes_USD*obj.TransferenciaV) / selectedFactorNumeros * selectedCambio).toFixed(0))),
                  backgroundColor: dataGrafVentas.map(obj => obj.TransferenciaV < 0.7 ? '#b71c1c' : obj.TransferenciaV < 0.8 ? '#f6734b' : '#8bc34a'),
                },
              ],
            }} 
            style={{ width: '800px', height: '400px' }}/>
```

The problem is my bar change the color depends of the value of `obj.TransferenciaV`, so if i have bars with more than a color, the legend just have 1 color.

I need a legend with two labels, first: Declarado por ... with `bg: '#007bb2'`
and the second: 'TRA' bg: with the 3 colors `#b71c1c`, `#f6734b` and `#8bc34a`